# Check button from another ViewController

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to an event application. I can add events to Firebase database and retrieve them. When I click the add button from my viewController, event's informations adding to Firebase database. But it can't show on my tableViewController until I logged out and log in again.

Here my retrieve code:

```
private func loadPlaces() {


        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            let images = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            // self.places.removeAll()
            for (_, value) in images {
                  let userToShow = events()
                if let img = value["pathToImage"] as? String,
                    let eventDate = value["event date"] as? String,
                    let name = value["event name"] as? String
                    //let information = value["information"] as? String
                {


                  //  self.places.append(historicalPlaces(img: img , name: name2, inf:information))

                     userToShow.eventImages = img
                    userToShow.eventDates = eventDate
                    userToShow.eventnames = name
                   // userToShow.information = information
                    self.event.append(userToShow)

                }


            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        //  ref.removeAllObservers()

    }
```

and this is my uploadPost code:

```
import UIKit
import os.log
import Firebase
class UploadPost: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectImageBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventInf: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var addBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var eventDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addEvent: UIBarButtonItem!

    var picker = UIImagePickerController()

    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        picker.delegate = self
        createDatePicker()
    }

    func createDatePicker(){

        //format for picker

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime

        // toolbar

        let toolbar = UIToolbar()

        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        // bar button item

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

        eventDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

        //assigning date picker to text field

        eventDate.inputView = datePicker

    }
    func donePressed(){

        //format date

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short

        eventDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            self.eventImage.image = image
            selectImageBtn.isHidden = true
            addBtn.isHidden = false
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any) {

        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func addEventPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    }



    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        AppDelegate.instance().showActivityIndicator()

        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://bauventdemo.appspot.com")

        let key = ref.child("events").childByAutoId().key
        let imageRef = storage.child("events").child(uid).child("\(key).jpg")

        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.eventImage.image!, 0.6)

        let uploadTask = imageRef.put(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicatos()
                return
            }

            imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let url = url {
                    let feed = ["userID" : uid,
                                "pathToImage" : url.absoluteString,
                                "event name" : self.eventName.text!,
                                "event date" : self.eventDate.text!,
                                "author" : FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.displayName!,
                                "event information" : self.eventInf.text!,
                                "postID" : key] as [String : Any]

                    let postFeed = ["\(key)" : feed]

                    ref.child("posts").updateChildValues(postFeed)
                    AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicatos()

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })

        }

        uploadTask.resume()



    }




    }
```

My code check database only when I login so, how can I check firebase database and retrieve them when I add new Event ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not updating the table is because you are trying to reload the table in background thread.
Instead, reload it in the main thread. Like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Updated code

```
private func loadPlaces() {


    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let images = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        // self.places.removeAll()
        for (_, value) in images {
              let userToShow = events()
            if let img = value["pathToImage"] as? String,
                let eventDate = value["event date"] as? String,
                let name = value["event name"] as? String
                //let information = value["information"] as? String
            {


              //  self.places.append(historicalPlaces(img: img , name: name2, inf:information))

                 userToShow.eventImages = img
                userToShow.eventDates = eventDate
                userToShow.eventnames = name
               // userToShow.information = information
                self.event.append(userToShow)

            }


        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
    //  ref.removeAllObservers()

}
```

Comment: thank you but i cannot find where i can add that codes in my codes. Could you tell me?

Comment: The last line of `func loadPlaces()`, you are doing `self.tableview.reload()`, instead of that, do like this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried add refresh button which retrieve data from database as a workaround.

```
 @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {

       loadPlaces()


    }
```

and I put this code to prevent duplicate events.

```
self.event.removeAll()
```